# is there a way to configure payload sent by sonarqube webhooks?

Tags: sonarqube, webhooks

i want to send sonarqube code coverage / smells numeric analysis values in addition to the quality gates status. webhooks seem ideal for my task but they only send quality gates status, is there a way to customize/configure webhooks?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a way to configure the webhook payload. However, you *could* use a webhook to notify some intermediate system, which would then use [web services](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api) to retrieve the other values you're interested in and pass them on to the target system.